# Algolia search calculate price

Tags: search, full-text-search, algolia

I'm using algolia search as my search engine. But there is a problem with displaying the correct price with the results. The price is calculated based on search parameters so it can't be indexen in the records. Where should i calculate the price? Its a cap service where you can find drivers with ratings, name, company info. Price is calculated based in price for each mile. The search input is from > to location. Thanks. Im using php with JS results.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best way to deal with that is to call a backend API endpoint on your end to compute the "dynamic" prices of the results returned by Algolia. I would go for an AJAX call as soon as you receive the results, before rendering them providing for each `objectID` of the results set its price.

Comment: Hi redox, Thanks for your quick answer. That was also one of my solutions but what about filtering (or sorting) on that price. Out of the box Angolia has amazing features for filtering/sorting/faceting data. Would there be a solution do you thing? We could switch out Angolia for some other service maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately, to reach optimal performances at search time, the Algolia engine requires you to configure your sort orders at indexing time (statically). Having totally dynamical ordering is not supported but you can have several of them using the master/slave feature: https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/index-configuration/what-are-slaves-indices-and-what-are-their-benefits

Answer (score 1):

The issue with sorting or filtering by a dynamic value is that you need to first calculate that value...

> e.g. Price = geo-distance(from user position to destination) * rate-per-mile + flag-drop

...for each document which *could* be valid.

If you have a lot of documents, and no way to filter your selection down before running your calculation, then the processing for your custom ranking will take the same computational effort as would processing a SQL query (requiring a full table scan).

Algolia, so far, seems to be all about speed.  They build the data structures to support that speed at index-time.  The current support for `customRanking` is limited to sorting by a custom list of fields asc/desc.

You can implement what you describe using [Solr](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) using *function score* queries.

---

And since you probably don't have more than a few thousand drivers to run this query calculation against, the performance issue (mentioned first) may not be a big concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connectRange } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';
import { Paragraph } from '../atoms';

const priceRange = [
  { id: 1, min: undefined, max: undefined, title: 'All' },
  { id: 2, min: 20, max: 99, title: 'Under $99' },
  { id: 3, min: 100, max: 499, title: '$100 - $499' },
  { id: 4, min: 500, max: 999, title: '$500 - $999' },
  { id: 5, min: 1000, max: 2499, title: '$1000 - $2499' },
  { id: 6, min: 2500, max: 4999, title: '$2500 - $4900' },
  {
    id: 7,
    min: 5000,
    max: 8900,
    title: 'Over $5,000',
  },
];

const PricingFilter = ({ refine }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selected) {
      refine({ min: selected?.min, max: selected?.max });
    }
  }, [selected]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {priceRange &&
        priceRange.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <a
                onClick={() => {
                  setSelected({
                    min: item.min || undefined,
                    max: item.max || undefined,
                  });
                }}
                role="button"
                aria-hidden="true"
                className="filter-item-wrapper">
                <Paragraph
                  size="6"
                  className={item.id ? 'has-text-weight-bold my-1' : 'my-1'}>
                  {item.title}
                </Paragraph>
              </a>
            </li>
          );
        })}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default connectRange(PricingFilter);
```